# SQL: Ranking Clicks by Customer ID and Time Stamp

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

I am reaching out for help with a ranking problem I have. What I want to accomplish is this: rank ref marker clicks partitioned by customer_id and hit_datetime so that the last item clicked by a customer is ranked with 1.

For example, in the sample data below,  customer_id 836283461 clicked on five different ref markers. However, I would like the last ref marked clicked by that customer on that day to be ranked 1st.

```
 Rank |   Hit Day   |  Time Stamp  |  Cust Id   |            Ref Marker
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1  |  13-DEC-15  |   23:06:24   |  836283461 |  a_mt_contactus_ts1_d12_d29
   1  |  13-DEC-15  |   23:06:33   |  836283461 |  a_mt_contactus_ts1_d13_d23_d34
   1  |  13-DEC-15  |   23:07:42   |  836283461 |  a_mt_contactus_ts1_d17
   1  |  13-DEC-15  |   23:07:49   |  836283461 |  a_mt_contactus_ts1_d12_d29
   1  |  13-DEC-15  |   23:07:54   |  836283461 |  a_mt_contactus_ts1_d13_d23_d35
```

[image]

Here is my query (apologizes for the formatting):

```
SELECT 
    row_number () over(
        partition by wma.customer_id, (to_char( wma.hit_datetime, 'HH24:MI:SS' )) 
        ORDER BY to_char( wma.hit_datetime, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) DESC
        ) 
    Hit_Rank,
    wma.hit_day, 
    to_char( wma.hit_datetime, 'HH24:MI:SS' ),
    wma.customer_id, 
    wma.ref_marker
FROM source_table wma
```

I believe I have to use some sort of max value function in my time stamp partition but haven't been able to figure out exactly how to do it.

----Revised Query----

I converted the time stamp to seconds and it organized the results as depicted in the above image.

```
SELECT
    row_number () over(
        partition by wma.customer_id ORDER BY (
            to_char(wma.hit_datetime,'HH24')*3600 
            + to_char(wma.hit_datetime,'MI')*60 
            + to_char(wma.hit_datetime,'SS')
            )   DESC
        ) Hit_Rank,
    wma.hit_day, 
    to_char( wma.hit_datetime, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
    to_char(wma.hit_datetime,'HH24')*3600 
        + to_char(wma.hit_datetime,'MI')*60 
        + to_char(wma.hit_datetime,'SS')
        AS total_seconds,
    wma.customer_id, 
    wma.ref_marker
FROM source_table wma
    AND wma.hit_day = '13-dec-15'
    AND wma.customer_id in (836283461, 1147442153, 13746668625);
```

Comment: why are using to_char on your dates?  don't you want to order by the date not a character representation thereof?

Comment: Good point. Hadn't thought of it. Something like convert(wma.hit_datetime, 'HH24:MM:SS')?? - Not sure of the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1):

is this it? partition by the id and the day (using trunc there) and then ordering by the date including time descending.

```
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER ()
            OVER (PARTITION BY wma.customer_id, TRUNC (wma.hit_datetime)
                  ORDER BY wma.hit_datetime DESC)
            Hit_Rank,
         wma.hit_day,
         TO_CHAR (wma.hit_datetime, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
         wma.customer_id,
         wma.ref_marker
  FROM   source_table wma
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Everything is ranked as 1. Not sure why, though. I was able to get it to work using the revised query above.